# How to replace multiple consecutive textview ids using regex?

Tags: android, regex, android-studio

I have around 30 textView ids with names "textview519" , textview518, textview517 etc and I want to rename them the smart way using regex

In android studio I have this window and i can search and query using regex!

[image: ddd]

How do I replace the ids like the following:

- textView501 becomes tv1
- textView502 becomes tv2
- ...
- textView519 becomes tv19
- textView523 becomes tv23

etc ?

Comment: Are views in one file?if you can search ,you can replace.

Comment: yes, they are all in one file

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler, i could, but i also want to learn the regex expression of doing it! i want to do it the smart way

Comment: The regex to match what needs replacing would be: textView50?

Comment: all textView5xx would become tv1,tv2,tv3

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

replace textView5  => tv, then you get tv01 tv02 tv03 ... tv19.

replace tv0 => tv ,then you get tv1 tv2 ...tv19